# How to deploy a simple war file on JBOSS 7?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x, jboss5.x

I deployed a simple war file (vivek.war) which contains a simple index.jsp file successfully in `Jboss-5.X.X and Jboss-6.X.X.`
I simply placed the war file in `server\default\deploy`

And then went to `localhost:8080/vivek/index.jsp` and everything was fine.

But Similarly, for Jboss-as-7.1.1, I deployed the war file in standalone `standalone\deployments` and started `\bin\standalone.sh` and then went to `localhost:8080/Hello/index.jsp` does not display the file.
it shows `HTTP Status 404-/vivek/` `(description The requested resource (/axis2/) is not available.)` in the browser.

What is the procedure to deploy a simple war file on Jboss-as-7.1.1 and how i get in browser.

if nay one have idea please help me?

Thanx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should PUT an empty flag file **warname**.dodeploy (ex. vivek.war.dodeploy) in your deployments directory.

More information about flag files is available in the README.TXT in the deployments directory.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, my JBoss 7.1.1 do not need .dodeploy file in deployments directory. Its enough simply to copy .war or .ear or ejb.jar to deployments dir for server to start deployment process. Please provide server.log to see the details. Do you set context-root tag in META-INF/web.xml or application.xml?

Answer (score 1):

While deploying a war project in Jboss AS7 ,one either copy a so-called exploded web application, i.e non-compressed,  or a compressed web application resource .WAR file to this location ${jboss.server.base.dir}/standalone/deployments/

- When one choose to deploy the project in the non-compressed or exploded-directory-form, one
  need to specify marker file .dodeploy e.g.
  vivek.war.dodeploy if folder name is vivek.war
- When One choose to deploy the project in a compressed web application resource form , No flag file is required.

*You can refer following resources for more details

    1. A useful link for this is as follows [Link for deployments in JBoss
       AS 7](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/7.0.x/deployer-howto.html)

    2. For extensive details you can have a look at the
    ${jboss.server.base.dir}/standalone/deployments/README.txt file
    located at the location*

> non-compressed implies it is
>   simple directory structure you  get from jar file after unzipping it
>   example of directory structure is below -

```
   vivek.war   
      |-index.jsp    
      |- WEB-INF   
          |- web.xml
```

Answer (score -1):

Its very simple, copy your war and paste it inside your `standalone\deployments` and run `standalone.bat` from your `bin` directory in windows. If you are on Linux, run `standalone.sh` from your `bin` directory.