# Eclipse Kepler JBoss AS 7.1.1 community publishing copies empty war directories to the deployment folder

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I have Eclipse Kepler with JBoss tools installed.  Also an external JBoss AS 7.1.1 community server.  When I go to publish my applications it copies empty war directories to the standalone/deployments folder.  I have this working on another machine with the exact same set up.  I copied the workspace and jboss over to the new machine (both macs).  The file privileges on both machines appear to be the same. If I manually copy the war files to the deployment folder and try to kick off the standalone.sh jboss appears to hang on startup.

The deployments/server.log file doesn't seem to reveal anything.  It is showing the same thing in the eclipse console which is deploying empty war directories:

```
16:10:05,099 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5)     JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "myAppWS-REST.war"
16:10:05,099 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "myAppCrawlerManager.war"
16:10:05,099 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "mysql-connector-java.jar"
16:10:05,099 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "myAppWeb.war"
16:10:05,848 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
16:10:05,919 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/myAppMessagingDB]
16:10:05,920 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/myAppPD]
16:10:05,920 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/myAppWSDB]
16:10:05,946 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/myAppWebDB]
16:10:06,568 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /myAppWeb
16:10:06,568 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /myAppCrawlerManager
16:10:06,568 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /myAppWS-REST
16:10:06,574 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
16:10:06,574 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started in 24528ms - Started 282 of 369 services (82 services are passive or on-demand)
16:10:06,655 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559:      Deployed "mysql-connector-java.jar"
16:10:06,656 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "myAppWS-REST.war"
16:10:06,657 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "myAppWeb.war"
16:10:06,657 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "myAppCrawlerManager.war"
16:10:06,657 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2)    JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014776:    Newly corrected services:
  service jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql-connector-java_jar (no longer required)
```

When I copy wars manually and try to startup via bin/standalone.sh  it hangs only displaying this in the terminal:

```
=========================================================================

JBoss Bootstrap Environment

JBOSS_HOME: /Users/doug/Apps/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

JAVA: java

JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+TieredCompilation -Xms64m -Xmx512m -   XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -  Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -  Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -  Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml

=========================================================================

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
21:29:00,179 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
21:29:01,847 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
21:29:01,970 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
```

Comment: See this post. May be it will help you.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797931/how-to-deploy-a-simple-war-file-on-jboss-7

Comment: That did not help.  The readme.txt mentions the marker files but doesn't mention anything about an 'empty' or any other flag.  Nonetheless I tried copying the wars there and creating the .dodeploy files along with adding the word 'empty' to them.  I then tried to start manually with standalone.sh and it still hangs.  Also, setting the empty flag or dodeploy files doesn't address the other problem that the war files are not being published to jboss from eclipse.  I don't think the other post mentioned this problem - only that jboss wasn't displaying the jsp correctly.